# Using Threads , to send response and continue with another task in Web application in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to C# and working on a Web Service project. I am having a scenario as below :
1. From web i will get the parameters
2. With the request i construct and start a set of test cases ,

this is time taking and user may not wait for almost 40 mins to an hour.
 Instead **Can i send the response back to the browser  to say that the execution is initiated ?** and as a background thread will run the next task.

Any idea or info will be of great help. **I will have to use C# and ASP.net as my api's for UCMA are in c#**. Basically i want to do something like:

```
var threads = new List<Thread>
        {
            new Thread(() => sendResponse(fileLogger,execution)),// expecting this to send the response back to browser.
            new Thread(() => goAheadWithlongerTimetakingTask(fileLogger))
        };
        threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
        threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
```

Once the second thread is done i would kill both the threads in Finally.

If this is not a better solution, can you suggest a better one ?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: In addition to asking the question as @Servy noted, when [edit] the post please make sure to add results of your research to the post. Right now it is not showing any. As you've obviously searched for https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+asp.net+long+running+task and found that it is in generally bad idea to have long running tasks in ASP.Net it is not clear why post shows such sample... (post likely be downvoted due to lack of *demonstrated* research)

Comment: I have got less knowledge than i was expecting from STACKOVERFLOW due to answers like this. I see them as ego answers rather than anything. Never mind the downgrades as my research doesnt need any certification because ITS MY WORK than just time pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess with threads in ASP.NET.

Instead, make the initial request schedule a task with a tool like HangFire or Quartz.NET. Then, have a Windows Service running that knows to watch for those scheduled tasks and execute them. Allow the web client (browser) to poll (or, if you want to get fancy, use something like SignalR) to check the status of the task, and when it's done retrieve the result.

Scott Hanselman has a great post about different strategies you can use for running background tasks in ASP.NET [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). I recommended the Hangfire/Quartz.NET strategy because the 40-minutes-to-1-hour timespan you're talking about is easily enough time for ASP.NET to get shut down while you're trying to execute the background task, so you'll definitely want to offload that to a separate app.

Comment: Thankyou StriplingWarrior for an answer which actually HELPS!! , Hangfire seems to be option. I will try it.